# How often do you get the robot prompt? I've gotten it every time for the past week now. . .

Tags: support, status-completed, captcha

I've noticed that I get prompted and asked if I'm a robot every time recently. I'm curious if this was due to my machine or the site flagging me. And this has been on multiple machines, on different networks with different ISPs (AFAIK).

I guess the only correlation I can figure out so far is I've used Chrome on all these machines.

I know I can't ask how the feature is implemented because that defeats the whole purpose of the feature, but what might be causing me to get it so frequently?

Comment: Looking at the logs, I'm betting you have some sort of ad blocker installed that interferes with some of our spam prevention mechanisms. Do you?

Comment: @balpha: Yeah, my ad blockers are pretty aggressive. I should probably think about whitelisting some sites. BTW, you didn't have to dig through the logs **just** for something like this.  I appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 8):

How are you posting?

If you compose your post off-line (in your text editor of choice) and then simply paste the text into the input box and hit "Post" you will, more often than not, trigger the robot Captcha.

You are using the site in exactly the same way that a robot would use the site.

Humans, in contrast, take their time. They typing into the input box and then it "Post" some 10's of seconds or even minutes later.

There are probably other rules of which I'm not aware but this seems to be the one that trips me up most often.

Comment: I find it comes up when you keep trying to edit your newly created answer as well.

Comment: I compose in the input box. I'm not fancy, nor do I need to compose in a text editor. Although I do with the add comment box was a little bigger by default.

Comment: @surfasb - don't know then. Sorry.

Comment: I don't get the prompts now. The robot guards must have the Wednesdays. . .

Answer (score 6):

It turns out your ad blockers were blocking some things that they shouldn't have been -- and this made you look a lot more like a bot to us.

Comment: Maybe I really am. . . Clank Clank.